# .well Equal height divs dont clear properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

New to Bootstrap guys - so please excuse my ignorance. Im having a problem with the responsiveness of a particular layout.

Here is the full screen fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/subdes/M48jH/5/embedded/result/

```
<div class="row-fluid">


     <div class="span9 black well">

        <div class="span4 grey  no-margin">
           <h1>A</h1>
            Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac    cursus commodo, tortor mauris c
           <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="span4 grey  no-margin">
           <h1>B</h1>
           Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac   curs    us commodo, tortor mauris   eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris         Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris   eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
           <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="span4 grey  no-margin">
           <h1>C</h1>
           Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
           <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span12  green no-margin">
              <h1>D</h1>
           </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="span3 competition well black ">
      <h1>E</h1>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details</a></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Ive implemented the jquery "well" equal height div fix on the left (span9) and right (span3) spans. However when minimised; although span3 floats under span9 - the contents of the divs inside span9 spill out over span9 and into span3 - rather than being contained

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've wrapped your three divs with `.span4` class inside div with `.row-fluid` class and now is working fine. Please see official [Twitter Bootstrap documentation about scaffolding (fluid nesting)](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#global).

Here is code:

```
<div class="container">


<!-- **************   CAROUSEL   ****************** -->
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9 black well">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4 grey  no-margin  ">
                    <h1>A</h1>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris c
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="span4 grey  no-margin  ">
                    <h1>B</h1>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris   eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris         Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris   eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="span4 grey  no-margin   ">
                    <h1>C</h1>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12  green no-margin  "><h1>D</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span3 competition well black ">
          <h1>E</h1>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

and i've placed your jQuery code in right place inside jsfiddle. Also, replaced `.load()` function with `.ready()` function. Check it now http://jsfiddle.net/M48jH/9/embedded/result/

NOTE: If you just resize browser window, you will see problem again. If you refresh if after resize, problem is gone. I can fix that with `.resize()` function. But in any case, when you resize window, you will have `.span3` div with same height as `.span9` div.